# File Transfer android

Tags: android, asyncsocket

I'm working on an **android application** that founds all the devices connected to the **same network** via WiFi, now i want to send files from my android application, the receiver device may be an **android device or anything else(windows or mac etc)**. 
I'm new to android programming and i don't know how it will be done, only i want to do is to send and receive files from my application,
Is it possible if yes then how??
Thanks in advance and sorry for poor english

Comment: via Bluetooth or Internet ?

Comment: provide me the library or sample cade, or a tutorial to do this.

Comment: which way do you wanna send files using Bluetooth or via Server through Internet connection ?

Comment: i'm using WiFi for connectivity

Comment: Does your receiver device have your app installed ?

Comment: all the devices are connected to the same network via WiFi

Comment: receiver device have no application installed, this is what i want to verify that is it possible or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send a file from your app to another device, you need to have a receiving app in the receiver device, otherwise it won't be possible,

There is a possibility is to use built-in NFC check here [NFC](https://developer.android.com/training/beam-files/send-files.html)

EDIT

you mentionned sending from your app to another this can be done by uploading your file to a remote server then downloading it from that remote server again

here is a snippet on how to upload it

```
String url = "http://yourserver";
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
        "yourfile");
try {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

    InputStreamEntity reqEntity = new InputStreamEntity(
            new FileInputStream(file), -1);
    reqEntity.setContentType("binary/octet-stream");
    reqEntity.setChunked(true); // Send in multiple parts if needed
    httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    //Do something with response...

} catch (Exception e) {
    // show error
}
```

and here is a tutorial on how to download it from the receiving app [Download from remote server](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/04/29/download-file-android-device-remote-server-custom-progressbar-showing-progress/)

Comment: ok what is the procedure to send and receive file, thanks Nadir for this information.

Comment: the procedure while having your app in both sides ?

Comment: i have found a library AllJoyn File Transfer Module, but i don't know how can i use this library.

Comment: https://www.alljoyn.org/docs-and-downloads/android
Is this useful for that purpose??

Comment: I'm not familliar with Alljoyn but from what I've seen you need both devices compatible with Alljoyn which is not the case right now

Comment: ok then how can i send and receive file at-least in between android devices that have same application and connected to the same network as well. Is there any tutorial available.

Comment: i don't want to use internet, i want to do this locally via WiFi.